# variable re-identification causing an infinite loop

Tags: c++

Why does this code cause an infinite loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int y = 5;
    while (y < 6) {
        int y = 7;
        cout << y << endl;
    }
}
```

yet removing the "int" in the while statement makes it run once normally?
(

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int y = 5;
    while (y < 6) {
        y = 7;
        cout << y << endl;
    }
}
```

)

Comment: Read up on variable scope. In the first example you have two `y`s. The `y` that is set to 7 is not in scope when `y` is tested by the loop.

Comment: Do not write crap code - problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you have observed is called [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).
This means that a variable is "shadowed" by another variable in an inner scope.
(iBug has already provided a link to the C++ scope rules)
The outer scope (in your case `while(y < 6)`) can not access the inner scope (in your case `int y = 7;`) and vice versa. Both have the same name, but they are completely separate variables in separate scopes.

This is a very common source for errors (you also find a lot of them here) and doesn't only happen with loops and other scope brackets, but also very often with class members. Imagine a class:

```
class MyClass {
    int a;
public:
    void getA( int a ) { return a; }
};
```

`getA()` defines a parameter `a`, which shadows the class member `a`. This is at least bad style, but even more probable a source of errors. We don't know - did you want to return the member `a` or did you really mean the parameter? So this should be avoided.

Here's a real life example on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48275172/2328447) - see my comment below the question (regarding the 3rd constructor)

Possibilities to avoid these kind of errors are:

- Use highest possible compiler warnings and perhaps even warnings as errors. Compilers can warn about those kind of shadowing issues.
- Use a name scheme. A common scheme is members with a `m`, `m_` prefix, a `_` suffix and the like. If the member name in the `MyClass` would have been `m_a`, this would have reduced confusion. Of course this doesn't help in your example, but it's a good idea nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

In this loop:

```
while (y < 6) {
    int y = 7;
    cout << y << endl;
}
```

The inner `y` is not accessible in the condition test.

If you remove the `int` in the loop, you're simply assigning a new value to the variable defined outside `while`, thus terminating it.

Look up Scope on [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).